# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from unknown!7788Kmk#8)

Tags: r, emacs

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from unknown!7788Kmk#8)

Im getting the error:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from unknown!7788Kmk#8) : object 'nickname' not found.`

**CODE**

```
 |                            | nickname |   d7Li |   x |
 |----------------------------+----------+--------+-----|
 | dd\_ol\_dhofar132b111@5012 | ol1a     |   24.2 |  48 |
 | dd\_ol\_dhofar132b111@5013 | ol1a     |   22.5 |  91 |

 # dataset

     d7Li.ol1a <- subset(tbl,subset=(nickname=="ol1a"))$d7Li
     x.ol1a    <- subset(tbl,subset=(nickname=="ol1a"))$x
     xlim       <- c(0, 750)
      ylim       <- c(-30, 30)
      legend <- c( "dhofar132" )
      col    <- c("red")
      pch    <- c(16,17)
     par(mar=c(2,2,0,0))
     plot(1,0,type="n",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,log="x")
    lines(d7Li.ol1a , x.ol1a ,pch=pch[1],col=col[1])
    legend("topleft",legend,pch=15,col=col)
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check how nickname is spelt in your tbl dataframe. R is case sensitive.

Comment: After which command does the error occur?

Comment: The error occurs after the command 
d7Li.ol1a <- subset(tbl,subset=(nickname=="ol1a"))$d7Li

Comment: do str(tbl) and show us the output

Answer (score 2):

The column "nickname" does not exist in the data.frame tbl. You can find out what the column names are by using colnames(tbl). Copy the name exactly. As LyzandeR mentioned, R is case sensitive.

Also, you could do this by using:

```
d7Li.ol1a <- subset(tbl,subset=(nickname=="ol1a"), select = "d7Li")
```

This is not necessarily better. Just another way to use subset.